# add column with specific values in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Write the code in mysql that add column color (varchar(20)) in table boats, default value is 'pink' ,  values in that column that are not allowed are : 'white','black', 'red'( other values are  allowed !! )

ALTER TABLE Boats
add column colors varchar(20) DEFAULT 'white' 
... ?

check constraint is ignored in mysql!

Comment: Since this is an assignment or exam question I won't give you a complete answer, but... You have almost everything you need, but check the documentation for the `ENUM()` type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: What about the opposite ... example , values that arent allowed in that column are 'white' , 'black' ,'red ' ?  THANKS FOR THE HELP !

Comment: Check constraints

Comment: Check constraints are ignored in mysql, other alternatives ?